# Rewrite Urls without breaking real files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So i'm pretty terrible at `RewriteRule` and `.htaccess`, and I've been trying to create a RewriteRule which allows me to redirect any request that doesn't already exist in the directory through index.php.

It looks like this at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?name=$0 [L]
```

However once I started trying to run ajax requests from a redirected url it breaks and returns the whole redirected page instead of the return data of any script that is in the directory. I'm pretty confused as to how I can make this work. \

What I want to be able to do is to be able to rout every non-real request through index.php and every other request as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sneak in another `RewriteCond` using a RegEx, in case you can find one (or more) for you *normal* requests. Something like

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^*your* *RegEx* *for* *normal* *request*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?name=$0 [L]
```

Comment: for a normal request I just want it to run as normal.

Comment: Yes, the condition I added kinda says "if `REQUEST_FILENAME` doesn't start with *your* *RegEx* *for* *normal* *request*, then redirect using the Rule underneath"....

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I still get a printout of my index.php rerout

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you've tried. Update your question maybe?

Comment: So the issue was that it was not working with xampp, but when I tried it live online it worked. o.O Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your htaccess code is correct. "-f" checks for a valid file and "-d" for a valid directory.

My guess is that you issuing relative ajax requests from an url like */some-dir/another-path/* which is internally rewritten to *index.php?name=/some-dir/another-path/*. A relative ajax request to ie *my-ajax-data.php* will be made to */some-dir/another-path/my-ajax-data.php*, and not */my-ajax-data.php* as you might think. Try using absolute URLs in the ajax requests. Well, it's just a shot in the dark.